# Procurar e exibir itens de objetos aninhados com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho duas listas, a aggregation me traz os codigos das categorias e a lista categories traz todas as categorias que tenho cadastrada. Preciso procurar as categorias em categories usando os ids do aggregation para criar uma nova lista somente com esse filtro. No caso de categorias que são filhas (propriedade children) preciso colocar nessa nova lista a categoria pai e a categoria filha.

Exemplo, no cado do id 22 (martelo de borracha) eu teria que exibir não só o martelo de borracha como também seus parents: ferramentas e martelo.

```
var aggregation = [
        {id: 1},
        {id: 12},
        {id: 22}        
      ]

  var categories = [
    {
      code: 1,
      name: "papelaria",
      children: [
        {
          code: 12,
          name: "papel",
          parentCode: 1,
          children: []
        },
        {
          code: 13,
          name: "lapis",
          parentCode: 1,
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      code: 2,
      name: "ferramentas",
      children: [
        {
          code: 21,
          name: "martelo",
          parentCode: 2,
          children: [
            {
              code: 22,
              name: "martelo de borracha",
              parentCode: 21,
              children: []
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      code: 3,
      name: "móveis",
      children: []
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Dê um exemplo de saída.

Comment: Por exemplo se eu filtrar pelo id 22, que é do item martelo de borracha, teria que retornar um array (ou de qualquer outra forma) os objetos de code 2, 21 e 22.

Comment: Certo, mas isso vai incluir os filhos também? Qual é o formato exato da saída? Mostre a saída esperada para o exemplo que você deu. Pode usar o botão [edit] para adicionar os detalhes à pergunta.

Comment: Além disso, você tem já algum código e está dando problema ou está querendo saber sobre o algoritmo a ser usado?

Comment: Fiz o código mas nao consegui trazer tres niveis de categoria e, não tenho mais esse cpdigo. Usando o exemplo do martelo de borracha a saida pode ser assim: 
[
 {code: 2, name: "ferramentas"},
 {code: 21, name: "martelo"},
 {code: 22, name: "martelo de borracha"}
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema pode ser resolvido com recursividade:

```js
var categories = [
    {
      code: 1,
      name: "papelaria",
      children: [
        {
          code: 12,
          name: "papel",
          parentCode: 1,
          children: []
        },
        {
          code: 13,
          name: "lapis",
          parentCode: 1,
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      code: 2,
      name: "ferramentas",
      children: [
        {
          code: 21,
          name: "martelo",
          parentCode: 2,
          children: [
            {
              code: 22,
              name: "martelo de borracha",
              parentCode: 21,
              children: []
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      code: 3,
      name: "móveis",
      children: []
    }
  ]
  
  function filtrarCategorias(id, categorias, resultado){
    resultado = resultado ? resultado : [];
    for(var i = 0;i<categorias.length;i++){
      var categoria = categorias[i];
      resultado.push(categoria);
      if (categoria.code == id){
        return resultado;
      }
      if(categoria.children.length > 0){
        resultado = filtrarCategorias(id, categoria.children, resultado);
        if(resultado.length > 1)
          return resultado;
      }
      resultado.pop();
    }
    return [];
  }

console.log(filtrarCategorias(22, categories));
```

A lógica é simples: utilizamos uma lista como pilha, percorrendo-a em profundidade e adicionando os elementos a cada iteração. Se encontrarmos o elemento correto, retornamos a lista. Se chegarmos até o último filho e não encontrarmos nada, vamos retirando os elementos da pilha até chegarmos ao topo novamente. O processo se repete até que tenhamos percorrido todos os elementos ou tenhamos encontrado o elemento procurado.

Comment: Show, era isso mesmo!! Valeu